# How do I update OpenCV for ROS?

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I update OpenCV for ROS?
I have read that The ROS Electric currently using 2.3.
But I would like to try latest version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42119/how-do-i-update-opencv-for-ros?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I removed ROS OpenCV package and installed the latest source.

May require some tweaking to your own code and to ld.

And if you are using the full distro (desktop or desktop-full) may not be possible.

[This question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9899/how-to-use-very-latest-opencv-version-in-ros/) also has other possibilities: creating an overlay (also check [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) although it's for catkin).

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0